# select option value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

i have a bit of problem to deal with the option value in jquery. which i have 2 kind of select and one of theme contain an array. some how i dont know how to compared them.

example:

```
<select id="category">
   <option value="[1,2]"> category fruit</option>
   <option value="[3,4]"> category vegies</option>
</select>

<select id="article">
   <option value="1">banana</option>
   <option value="2">mango</option>
   <option value="3">letus</option>
   <option value="4">spinach</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
 $(function(){
       var $article = $('#article > option').each(function(){
            //var $v = $(this).val();
            //console.log($v);
            return $(this).val();

       });

       $('#categorie').on('change', function(){
            var $e = $(this).val();
            console.log($e);
            if($e == $article){
                // here should be the value from the article was choosed from category
            }else{
                console.log('there are no entries')
            }

       });

 })
```

but i dont know how to compare theme properly. and it should be if #category [1,2] selected then the #article 1 and 2 only shown in option and the other should be hidden. any kind of idea or suggestion thank you very much. best regard.

Comment: That is not an array you have as your value, it is just recognized as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that. It works for me.

Here is html.

```
<select id="category">
   <option value="[1,2]"> category fruit</option>
   <option value="[3,4]"> category vegies</option>
</select>

<select id="article">
   <option value="1">banana</option>
   <option value="2">mango</option>
   <option value="3">letus</option>
   <option value="4">spinach</option>
</select>
```

And here is jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function checkData(value){
            var $e = value;
            $('#article > option').each(function(index, item) {
                if ($e.indexOf($(item).val()) === -1) {
                    $(item).hide();
                } else {
                    $(item).show();
                }            
            });
        }
        $('#category').change(function(){
            checkData($(this).val());
        });

        checkData($('#category').val());
});
```

I think that may help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($e.indexOf($article)!=-1){

}else{
    console.log('there are no entries')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a typo `categorie`. It should be `category`

Try this

```
var opts = [];
  $('#article > option').each(function(){

            opts.push($(this).val());

  });
  console.log(opts)
  $('#category').on('change', function(){
            var $e = $(this).val();
           var present = false;
           $(opts).each(function(i,v){
                    if($e[1]==v){
                    present= true;
                    console.log($e[1])
                  }
           });

           if(!present){
            console.log('there are no entries')
           }

       });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dfwbLsn1/1/)

Comment: Thank you all, thank you so much for the quick answer. i learn something new from you guys. thanks you very much once again.

Answer (score 0):

The value inside first select element is not an array, it just a string, remove bracket and leave only number with comma separated like following :

**HTML**

```
<select id="category">
 <option value="1,2"> category fruit</option>
 <option value="3,4"> category vegies</option>
</select>

<select id="article">
 <option value="">chose</option>
 <option value="1">banana</option>
 <option value="2">mango</option>
 <option value="3">letus</option>
 <option value="4">spinach</option>
</select>
```

**Js**
*(first option)*

```
// use this
$('#category').change(function(){
  var cat = $( this ).val().split(',');
  $('#article option').hide()
  $.each(cat,function(i,e){
    $('#article option[value="'+e+'"]').show()
  })
});
```

*(second option)*

```
//or use this : filter out only matched element
var cacheElem = $('#article option').detach();
$('#category').change(function(){
  $('#article option').remove();
  var cat = $( this ).val().split(',');  
  var h = cacheElem.filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, cat) !== -1 && this
  });
  $('#article').append(h)
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/3mvk8nhr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this option, working example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd4Lgsq9/)

```
$('#categorie').on('change', function(){
    var $e = $(this).val();
    $('#article > option').each(function(index, item) {
      if ($e.indexOf($(item).val()) === -1) {
        $(item).hide();
      } else {
        $(item).show();
      }
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the select value `[1,2]`, then use `JSON.parse` to make that and array. Then you can search it.

```js
var $article = [];
$(function() {
  $article = $('#article > option').map(function() {
      return parseInt(this.value);
  }).get();
  console.log($article);
  $('#category').on('change', function() {
    var $e = JSON.parse(this.value);
    console.log($e);
    valid = false;
    $.each($e, function(i, val){
      valid = valid || $.inArray(val, $article) != -1;
    });
    if (valid)
       alert('Exists' + $e.join())
    else
      console.log('there are no entries')
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category">
  <option value="[1,2]">category fruit</option>
  <option value="[3,4]">category vegies</option>
</select>

<select id="article">
  <option value="1">banana</option>
  <option value="2">mango</option>
  <option value="3">letus</option>
  <option value="4">spinach</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your flexibility to change the category option value attribute but I took the liberty to take another approach to your issue.

I created an object with a list of possible items to display.
The select id="category" options value is the name of the list of items I want to display.

When the category changes I update the article select with only the list of items I want to show.

```
<select id="category">
   <option value="fruits"> category fruit</option>
   <option value="vegies"> category vegies</option>
</select>

<select id="article">
   <option value="1">banana</option>
   <option value="2">mango</option>
</select>
```

as for the JavaScript

```
$(function(){
                var items = {
          fruits: ["banana", "mango"],
          vegies: ["letus", "spinash"]
        };

       var current = items[0];

       var updateOptions = function(cat_in) {
        current = cat_in;
        output = "";

        for(var i = 0; i<items[cat_in].length; i++) {
          output += '<option value="'+i+'">'+items[cat_in][i]+'</option>'; 
        }

       return output;

       };

       $('#category').on('change', function(){
            var $e = $(this).val();
            if($e == current) return;

            var options = updateOptions($e);
            $("#article").empty().append(options);
       });

 });
```

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/marioandrade/mkt16n1g/1/

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple:

```
$('#category').on('change', function() {
  var currentCategory = $(this).val();
  // reset and show/hide group items
  $('#article').val("").find('option').each(function(index) {
    $(this).toggle(!(currentCategory.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1));
  });
}).triggerHandler('change');
```